# What if format for Getcapabilities document

Tags: geoserver, wms

I want to add capabilities URL for cascading a layer from remote WMS in Geoserver. What will be the exact format for Getcapabilities URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Format:

> http://{yourgeoserver}:{port}/geoserver/wms?Service=WMS&Request=GetCapabilities

## Working Example:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?Service=WMS&Request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

According to the WMS specification, the value part of name=[value]& parameter pairing is case sensitive, so the correct format here is actually:

http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?Service=WMS&Request=GetCapabilities&